Handling Promise.race better
Trying to write the flow logic for a drawing tool where user can enter a combination of keyboard inputs to draw complicated shapes on a canvas, to achieve this I'm trying to chain event listeners in a way that they remove themselves once done keeping global state clean. I would rather do this than keeping track hundreds of global state variabls that manages which listeners are active etc. I'm making progress but I'm stuck on recusive calls to Promise.race not sure if there's a better way to achieve this.
Using Promise.race in a recusive loop means that alot of the promises do not get resolved.
Is there a better way for me to do this?
function startCount(node) {
  const counter = Object.create(counterMethods);
  counter.node = node;
  counter.number = 0;
  counter.exitloopflag = false;
  return counter;
}

const counterMethods = {
  doCounter: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let handler = () => {
        this.node.removeEventListener("click", handler);
        console.log("lip");
        resolve("click");
      };
      this.node.addEventListener("click", handler);
    });
  },
  quit: function () {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let handler = (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          this.node.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
          console.log("lap");
          resolve("exit");
        }
      };
      this.node.addEventListener("keydown", handler);
    });
  },
  counterFlow: async function () {
    //if (this.exit) return;
    let result = await Promise.race([this.doCounter(), this.quit()]);

    if (result === "exit") {
      console.log(`You have pressed exit`);
      //  this.exit = true;
    } else if (result === "click") {
      this.number += 1;
      console.log(`You have clicked ${this.number} of times`);
      this.counterFlow();
    } else {
      console.log("code should not have run here");
    }
  },
};


@evolutionxbox - the code runs as is (after removing export of course)

I've updated it, it's just a proof of concept.

I see no problem with unresolved promises. They consume no resources.

@HeikoTheißen They do consume memory as long as there is something that can resolve them!

Ok the answer to this was pretty simple it seems, you just need to add both eventlisteners at the same time and remove them as soon as one is called. It's not elegant but it works:
export class StartCount {
  constructor() {
    this.number = 0;
    this.again = true;
    this.s = window.Storage;
  }

  addOne() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let handleClick = (e) => {
        this.number += 1;
        console.log("hello");
        console.log(`X:${e.clientX} Y:${e.clientY} counter:${this.number}`);
        document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick); //remove both here
        document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);
        resolve(0);
      };

      let handleKeydown = (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          console.log("Escaped");
          document.removeEventListener("click", handleClick);
          document.removeEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown);
          resolve(1);
        }
      };

      document.addEventListener("click", handleClick); //<-just call both here
      document.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeydown); // and here
    });
  }

  async flowLogic() {
    if (await this.addOne()) return;
    if (await this.addOne()) return;
    if (await this.addOne()) return;
    console.log(`end reached${this.again ? " again" : " ?"}`);
  }

  async doStartCount() {
    await this.flowLogic();
    document.dispatchEvent(this.s.modeNormal);
  }
}



I do not think that a recursive approach is necessary at all, but this is hard to say for certain because it is unclear what you want to achieve with it. Since you speak of a drawing tool, I assume that you want to prevent the handling of certain events depending on which event came before.
For example, an event that starts a drawing must be followed by another that finishes the drawing (or by the "Escape" button), but not by another "start drawing" event. This can be achieved with event handlers that are added only once, but whose behavior depends on a state variable.
The following snippet illustrates this: Clicking, dragging and releasing the mouse draws a rectangle with the start and end points as diagonally opposite corners. But pressing "Escape" during the dragging cancels the drawing.


var x, y;
var state = "idle";

document.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {
  if (event.key === "Escape") state = "inactive";
});
document.addEventListener("mousedown", function(event) {
  if (state === "idle") {
    x = event.x;
    y = event.y;
    state = "drawing";
  }
});
document.addEventListener("mouseup", function(event) {
  if (state === "drawing") {
    if (y <= event.y) {
      box.style.top = y + "px";
      box.style.height = (event.y - y) + "px";
    } else {
      box.style.top = event.y + "px";
      box.style.height = (y - event.y) + "px";
    }
    if (x <= event.x) {
      box.style.left = x + "px";
      box.style.width = (event.x - x) + "px";
    } else {
      box.style.left = event.x + "px";
      box.style.width = (x - event.x) + "px";
    }
    state = "idle";
  }
});
body {
  position: relative;
}

#box {
  border: solid 1px black;
  position: absolute;
}
<div id="box"></div>



The number of possible states can be much bigger, of course. From the example you gave for drawing a rectangle, I can imagine the following:



State before
User interaction
State after
Effect




idle
escape
inactive
drawing finished


idle
press "R"
rectangle
drawing rectangles


line
press "R"
rectangle
drawing rectangles


rectangle
escape
inactive
drawing finished


rectangle
click
drawing-rectangle



drawing-rectangle
escape
rectangle
rectangle abandoned


drawing-rectangle
click
rotating-rectangle
rectangle shown without rotation


rotating-rectangle
escape
rectangle
rectangle finished w/o rotation


rotating-rectangle
click
rectangle
rectangle finished with rotation


idle
press "L"
line
drawing lines


rectangle
press "L"
line
drawing lines


line
escape
inactive
drawing finished


line
click
drawing-line



drawing-line
click
drawing-line
line finished, next line started


drawing-line
escape
line
last line abandoned


...






A polygon can then be drawn as follows: The first line is established by the first two clicks, subsequent lines by one more click each, until escape is pressed.

Please put this important information into the question itself (use the "Edit" button), not in a comment.

Thanks I've updated.

I don't think there's an easy way to do this after all, I've resorted to using signals to abort the listeners not sure if this is in efficient but it does seem to work. Also in the mean time I learn how classes work so I've may have updated the code a little. Previously when I press "esc" I get "clack" console.logged out for as many times as I have clicked i.e. build up of exit event listerners from Promise.race however i've used a abort signal to turn those off every time now.
class StartCount {
  constructor(node) {
    this.node = node;
    this.number = 0;
    this.exit = false;
    this.abortController = new AbortController();
  }

  addOne() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let handler = (e) => {
        console.log(e.clientX, e.clientY);
        resolve("click");
      };
      this.node.addEventListener("click", handler, {
        once: true,
        signal: this.abortController.signal,
      });
    });
  }

  quit() {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      let handler = (e) => {
        if (e.key === "Escape") {
          console.log("clack");
          this.node.removeEventListener("keydown", handler);
          resolve("exit");
        }
      };
      this.node.addEventListener("keydown", handler, {
        signal: this.abortController.signal,
      });
    });
  }

  abortListener() {
    if (this.abortController) {
      this.abortController.abort();
      console.log("All event listeners aborted");
    }
  }

  resetController() {
    this.abortController = new AbortController();
  }

  async flowLogic() {
    let result = await Promise.race([this.addOne(), this.quit()]);
    this.abortListener();
    this.resetController();
    if (result === "exit") {
      this.exit = true;
      console.log("exit");
      document.dispatchEvent(window.return2Normal);
    } else if (result === "click") {
      this.number += 1;
      console.log(`You have clicked ${this.number} of times`);
      this.flowLogic();
    } else {
      console.log("code should not have run here");
    }
  }
}


